# SQL Server get ids in one table on Date criteria in table one and table two

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having problems getting the ids in TABLE A that satisfies the following criteria (I have tried a lot of different things and looked at various SO answers but cannot make it work. I looked into using `OVER(PARTITION BY TABLE_B.calendar))`:

1. Open (TABLE_B) should be equal to 1 on the first calendarDay (TABLE_B) on or after 10 days after startDate(TABLE_A).
2. endDate (TABLE_A) should be equal to the day found in 1) (i.e. the calendarDay for the respective id that satisfies the criteria).

Sample data:

**TABLE_A**:

```
    +----+------------+------------+
    | id | startDate  | endDate    |
    +----+------------+------------+
    | 1  | 2011-02-14 | 2011-03-14 |
    | 2  | 2012-12-19 | 2013-01-20 |
    | 3  | 2014-12-19 | 2015-01-21 |
    +----+------------+------------+
```

**TABLE_B**:

```
    +-------------+------+
    | calendarDay | open |
    +-------------+------+
    | 2011-03-14  | 1    |
    | 2011-03-16  | 0    |
    | 2013-01-20  | 1    |
    | 2013-01-21  | 1    |
    | 2015-01-21  | 0    |
    | 2015-01-22  | 1    |
    +-------------+------+
```

Desired result:

```
    +----+------------+------------+
    | id | startDate  | endDate    |
    +----+------------+------------+
    | 1  | 2011-02-14 | 2011-03-14 |
    | 2  | 2012-12-19 | 2013-01-20 |
    +----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Point 1 is "on the next 10 days" or "after 10 days"?

Comment: It should be 10 days OR more than 10 days.

Comment: How are these related? You said on or after 10 days after startDate but there's 3 startDates... and i assume many more

Comment: Sorry about not being clear enough. The 3 startDates (TABLE_A) should be evaluated independently against all the open (TABLE_B) calendarDays (TABLE_B). And yes there are more than 3 startDates - all of them should be evaluated independently (startDate is not unique, there are many occurences of the same startDate, but id is unique).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select a.*
from a cross apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from b
      where b.open = 1 and b.calendarDate >= dateadd(day, 10, a.startdate)
      order by b.calendarDate asc
     ) b
where b.calendarDate = a.endDate
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. I like your approach with cross apply!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CTE to first get the first calendar day:

```
with cteId(n, id, [open])
as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.id order by b.calendarDay) n, a.id, b.[open]
    from #TABLE_A a
    inner join #TABLE_B b on b.calendarDay >= DATEADD(day, 10, a.startDate)
)
```

... then just join it with TABLE_A

```
select a.*
from #TABLE_A a
inner join cteId c on a.id = c.id
where c.n = 1 and c.[open] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

Use `Exists`

```
select a.* 
from TABLE_A as a
where exists( 
              SELECT 1 
              FROM TABLE_B b
              where
              a.startDate <= DateAdd(day, 10, b.calendarDay) and b.[open] = 1
            ) 
and exists( 
             SELECT 1 
             FROM TABLE_B b
             where
             a.endDate  = b.calendarDay  and b.[open] = 1
            )
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/320111/15*

another way can try to use `join`

```
select a.* 
from TABLE_A as a 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT b.*,DateAdd(day, 10, b.calendarDay) addDay
  FROM TABLE_B b
  where b.[open] = 1
) b on a.startDate <= addDay and a.endDate = b.calendarDay
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/320111/19*

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use Exists here to look for the matching value

```
Select  * 
From    Table_A a
Where   Exists (
            Select  1
            From    Table_B b
            Where   b.[open] = 1
            And     b.calendarDay >= DateAdd(dd, 10, a.endDate)
            And     b.calendarDay = a.endDate)
        )
```

Comment: . . This doesn't check for the first calendar date in B that matches the first two conditions.